# How can I keep offset columns with a centered content column in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My first question as I am having some difficulty in maintaining a side navbar within an offset boostrap column.

I am a Technical Writer and still learning the platform.
I have a row with a set of columns that are offset:

```
    div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
```

My sidebar nav links are static with scrolling.

```
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-0  col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0 ">
                            <div class="topics">
                                <h4 class="sidenavheader">In this topic:</h4>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><a href="#First" title="Click here to learn about first time login" alt="Click here to learn about first time login">First Time Login</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Navigati" title="Click here to learn about Navigation" alt="Click here to learn about Navigation">Navigation</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Navigati2" title="Click here to learn about Navigation Home Page" alt="Click here to learn about Navigation Home Page">Removing elements</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#My" title="Click here to learn about My Self page" alt="Click here to learn about My Self page">My Self</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#My2" title="Click here to learn about My Company" alt="Click here to learn about My Company">My Company</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The problem arises when I shrink the window (at the 1200px range) the side navbar crunches in and the main content in the div above shifts to the right.
Shrinking the window more (@972 px) returns the content as centered and removes the sidebar (which is what i want).

So it appears that the media query at medium is the issue? I have tried many options and I guess I am missing something.

I really like this site. I could use a little help as for some reason I am not gleaning what I need to from the bootstrap documents or my searches.
Thank you.
JJ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is simply that you don't have the 12 available columns distributed properly for medium screen widths. Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/YMn9P0)**

Notice that I've removed the unnecessary offsets for the sidebar.